# Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to get window width and height at load and on resize; however, I get the following error. I do not see anything out of the ordinary with the html of the file.

*Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.*

*Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching `<div>` in `<div>`.*

*See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error*

*Component Stack*

*div*

*div*

*NavHeader*

*./app/components/NavHeader.js (24:107)*

*body*

*html*

---

NavHeader.js

```
'use client';
import Link from 'next/link'
import styles from 'styles/NavHeader.module.css'
import DensityMediumIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DensityMedium';
import { useState } from "react";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { auth } from "@/firebase";

export default function NavHeader() {
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);

  const [device, setDevice] = useState("");

  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1000) {
      if (device !== "small") {
        setDevice("small");
      }
    } else {
      if (device !== "desktop") {
        setDevice("desktop");
      }
    }
  }


  const clickHandler = () => {
    const x = document.getElementById("menuMobile");
    if (x.style.display === "flex") {
      x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "flex";
    }
  }

  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    let w = window.innerWidth;


    window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
      let w = window.innerWidth;
      if (w < 1000) {
        setDevice("small");
      } else {
        setDevice("desktop");
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.headerContainer}>
      <div className={styles.logo} />
      {(device === "desktop") &&
        <div id={"desktopMenu"} className={styles.desktopMenu}>
          <Link href={"/"}>HOME</Link>
          <Link href={"/about"}>ABOUT US</Link>
          <Link href={"/electricity"}>ELECTRICITY</Link>
          <Link href={"/pool-heating"}>POOL HEATING</Link>
          <Link href={"/contact-us"}>CONTACT US</Link>
          {user && <Link href={"/dashboard"} className={styles.signIn}>DASHBOARD</Link>}
          {!user && <Link href={"/sign-in"} className={styles.signIn}>CUSTOMER LOGIN</Link>}
        </div>
      }
      {(device === "small") &&
        <div>
          <DensityMediumIcon id={"menuIcon"} onClick={clickHandler} className={styles.expand} />
          <div id={"menuMobile"} className={styles.menuMobile}>
            <Link href={"/"} onClick={clickHandler}>HOME</Link>
            <Link href={"/about"} onClick={clickHandler}>ABOUT US</Link>
            <Link href={"/electricity"} onClick={clickHandler}>ELECTRICITY</Link>
            <Link href={"/pool-heating"} onClick={clickHandler}>POOL HEATING</Link>
            <Link href={"/contact-us"} onClick={clickHandler}>CONTACT US</Link>
            {user && <Link href={"/dashboard"} onClick={clickHandler}>DASHBOARD</Link>}
            {!user && <Link href={"/sign-in"} onClick={clickHandler}>CUSTOMER LOGIN</Link>}
          </div>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am using Next.js v14.1.0. Any help would be much appreciated.